# Error when installing php-gd

Tags: php, gd

I installed php with the remi repo and now I want to install php gd. 
I've tried to install php-gd for my CentOS 7 but I got this error:

```
sudo yum install php-gd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repos.redrockhost.com
 * epel: mirrors.syringanetworks.net
 * extras: centos.sonn.com
 * updates: mirror.compevo.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.4.16-23.el7_0.3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3 for package: php-gd-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.4.16-23.el7_0.3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3 for package: php-gd-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64
---> Package t1lib.x86_64 0:5.1.2-14.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-gd-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3
           Installed: php-common-5.5.17-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.17-2.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can somebody help me with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears that You may need to enable the remi-php55 repo too if you haven't already - I'm pretty sure you'd run something like `yum install php-gd --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55`

Comment: Thanks for your answer sa289! When I ran your command I got the following: http://fixee.org/paste/klij3zy/  It makes me nervous that it says that it will upgrade the php and php-common, etc. since this is a production server I don't want to screw it up.

Comment: @SaulOrtega You should have updated those already. This is a production server and you need to keep current on security updates. Because these repositories were disabled, you missed these updates.

Comment: Thank you so much @sa289 that was awesome, it fixed my problem!